# How to display success message after ajax form summit

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, forms

I've been working on this code I found somewhere. I use it to submit the Send to Friend form from a popup. It works but I can't get it to display the success message after it submits the form. Right now after it submits the form it just disappears. Maybe someone good at ajax can see what's the matter with it. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var formId = 'product_sendtofriend_form';
        var sendfriendForm = new VarienForm(formId, false);
        var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getSendUrl() ?>';
        function doAjax() {
            if (sendfriendForm.validator.validate()) {
                new Ajax.Updater(
                    { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                        method:'post',
                        asynchronous:true,
                        evalScripts:false,
                        onComplete:function(request, json) {
                            Element.hide(formId);
                            Element.show('formSuccess');
                        },
                        onLoading:function(request, json){
                            Element.show('formLoader');
                        },
                        parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
                    }
                );
            }
        }

        new Event.observe(formId, 'submit', function(e){
            e.stop();
            doAjax();
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code

```
onComplete:function(request, json) {
                            Element.hide(formId);
                            Element.show('formSuccess');
                        }
```

to:

```
onComplete:function(request, json) {                            
                            $('formSuccess').show();
                        }
```

Comment: It works that way but not how it needs to work. If I put `<div id="formSuccess" style="display:none">hello</div>' it replaces the div with the whole products details page and tries to put that into the popup. I would like it to show "hello" or go get another html document. I've tried everything I can think of. Thanks

Comment: updated answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you pointing me in the right place to look I figured out something that worked. I changed  `Element.show('formSuccess');` to  `Element.show('formSuccess2');` and added  the div like this `<div id="formSuccess2" style="display:none">hello</div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var formId = 'product_sendtofriend_form';
    var sendfriendForm = new VarienForm(formId, false);
    var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getSendUrl() ?>';
    function doAjax() {
        if (sendfriendForm.validator.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater(
                { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                    method:'post',
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json) {
                        Element.hide(formId);
                        Element.show('formSuccess2');
                    },
                    onLoading:function(request, json){
                        Element.show('formLoader');
                    },
                    parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
                }
            );
        }
    }

    new Event.observe(formId, 'submit', function(e){
        e.stop();
        doAjax();
    });
//]]>
</script>
```